# Why do my vue-router links sporadically lead to the wrong page (or don't work at all)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vuejs2, vue-router, event-listener

I have a strange bug in a Vue.js single-page application using Vue Router, where my links sometimes do not lead to the correct page, although the variable determining the target page is correct.

This is better seen than described, so I have deployed the app in its current state. Go to http://daggy1.watchduck.net/nodes/2 and click on a link in the parents/children section, and do the same again on the page where it leads you. You will see that sometimes the page where you go is not the right one, and sometimes the link simply does not work. The links in the full list on top always work fine.

Devtools are enabled, and both the click (`a click b`) and the page change (`a ----> b`) are logged to the console.

[image]

In the screenshot it can be seen, that clicking link *9* on page *11* led to page *2* instead of *9*.

I have uploaded the code on GitHub: https://github.com/watchduck/daggy

The links for the full list are in
[`Nodes.vue`](https://github.com/watchduck/daggy/blob/master/front/src/components/Nodes.vue)

```
<router-link v-for="node in nodes"
             :to="{name: 'node', params: {id: node.id, name: node.name}}"
             tag="li"
             active-class="active">
    <a>{{node.id}}: {{node.name}}</a>
</router-link>
```

while those in question are in 
[`NodeRelatives.vue`](https://github.com/watchduck/daggy/blob/master/front/src/components/NodeRelatives.vue).

```
<router-link v-for="relative in relatives"
             :to="{name: 'node', params: {id: relative.id, name: relative.name}}"
             tag="li"
             @click.native="clickDebug(relative.id)">
    <a>{{relative.id}}: {{relative.name}}</a>
</router-link>
```

Both `Nodes.vue` and `NodeRelatives.vue` are used in
[`Node.vue`](https://github.com/watchduck/daggy/blob/master/front/src/components/Node.vue).

What happens is logged to the console in two ways:

- `clickDebug` in `NodeRelatives.vue` logs the current page and the clicked link (`a click b`).
- The watcher in `Node.vue` logs the last and the new page (`a ----> b`).

Naturally I would like to know how to make my links behave correctly.

But I would also be glad about hints how to find a bug like this. How to debug Vue.js apps is an often asked question — and the answer is too often something like "use the Chrome extension". If someone can solve this using the Chrome extension, I would love to see that. I am sure a little debugging screencast would be very helpful to a lot of people.

---

**Edit 1:** As Slotheroo pointed out, the problem has to do with the `tag="li"` property and the nested anchor tag in `router-link`.
I removed them, and added a separate frontend with the new code:
Old: http://daggy1.watchduck.net/nodes/2  
New: http://daggy1a.watchduck.net/nodes/2

It is in a separate branch called `simple-router-links` on GitHub:
[`NodeRelatives.vue`](https://github.com/watchduck/daggy/blob/simple-router-links/front/src/components/NodeRelatives.vue)

(Just avoiding the problem is of course not the solution I am looking for.)

Initially we thought that the event listener for the `li` is causing the problem, but it turned out that that is just the `clickDebug` listener - added when the problem already existed.

---

**Edit 2:** The behaviour is not as sporadic as it seemed:

- After reloading the page, all the links work.
- Start with http://daggy1.watchduck.net/nodes/9, click parent 2, click parent 1. Link 1 does not work. (Same for starting with any child of 2, i.e. 3, 4, 5, 9.)
- Start with http://daggy1.watchduck.net/nodes/10, click parent 1, click child 2. Link 2 leads to 13.
- Start with http://daggy1.watchduck.net/nodes/1, click child 2, click parent 1, 2, 1, 2, 1... never fails. (Same for starting with 10.)

---

**Edit 3:** When the Axios call to the backend is replaced with static data, it works: http://daggy1b.watchduck.net/nodes/2
The code is in a separate branch called `static-data` on GitHub, which was later reduced to a minimal version
([1c](http://daggy1c.watchduck.net/nodes/2)):
https://github.com/watchduck/daggy/tree/static-data/front/src

When a timeout is put in `getNodeRelatives()`, the problem is back again. Surprisingly even when the delay is set to 0:

```
getNodeRelatives() {
    let f = () => {
        this.relativesInBothDirections = this.$store.state.nodeRelatives[this.id]
    }
    setTimeout(f, 0)
}
```

---

**Edit 4:** When the event listener is removed from the broken link, it will work. The screenshot below shows how the event listener from the broken link to page 1 is removed. Clicking it again will lead to page 1 - but as a hard reload of the page, and not within the app.

[image]

---

**Edit 5:** I opened an issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2305
For this I minimized the version with static data: http://daggy1c.watchduck.net/nodes/2

Answer (score 2):

This is a weird one for sure. I don't have it fully sorted out, but I'll share what I've learned.

For troubleshooting try this:

1. Open the Vue developer tools
2. Click on a router-link component, this will set the router-link component to be accessible as $vm0 in the console.
3. Go to the console and type `$vm0.to.params.id` and hit enter. This should show the expected value for the target id of the link. e.g. 1
4. Change the target id by typing something like `$vm0.to.params.id = 7` (assuming the value was previously not 7)
5. Click on the link in the window, it should now go to /nodes/7 instead of wherever it was previously set to go.

The weird thing about this is that it works for the 13 nodes links up top, but it does NOT work for the node relatives (parents/children). Changing the id for the to param does not affect where click on the link takes us.

Troubleshooting part 2:

1. Right click on one of the nodes links in the normal browser window and inspect it. This should open up the elements tab in the dev tools.
2. Click on the event listeners sub-tab. We can see that there is one listener for the click event on the `<a>` tag
3. Now right click and inspect one of the relatives links.
4. When reviewing the event listeners for the click event here, we can see that there are two -- one for the `<a>` tag and one for the `<li>` tag

This makes me think that perhaps those listeners somehow trigger different events, and perhaps it is the listener on the `<li>` tag that is directing to the wrong location.

One other piece of observational evidence I have is that when a route goes to the wrong link, it was usually the correct link for the previous page. I'll explain what I mean.

1st view: I'm looking at the page for Node 5. It has a parent of Node 2, and children Node 7, and Node 8. Note here that Node 7 is the first child listed.

We click on Node 2

2nd view: We're now on the page for Node 2. It has a parent of Node 1 and children of Nodes 9, 4, 5, and 3. Note that Node 9 is the first child listed. If we click on Node 9, it takes us to Node 7, which would have been the correct first child on the previous page! This suggests that somehow the links weren't updated properly, even though the data on the page looks like it's refreshed.

Things I would suggest to continue troubleshooting:

- Remove the tag="li" part of the router-links for relative nodes and see how they render then
- Try to make the way you iterate through node relatives as similar as you can to how you iterate through the nodes

  - Try iterating on the router-link instead of on the tr
- Try passing static data to the node relatives component. I wonder if there is some sort of latency with the axios call that is resulting in some sort of mismatch between the router-link information and the data.

Comment: Thanks. I am AFK over the weekend, and will try it Sunday evening.

Comment: The `tr` was a vestige, and I removed it. But it has nothing to do with the problem. That is indeed caused by the second event listener, which can be avoided by not using `tag="li"` - see my edit to the question. I will try your suggestion with the static data.

Comment: Also, what happens if you remove the clickDebug listener? Could that be adding a second listener that somehow screws up the call to the vue router listener?

Comment: Indeed, the event listener of the `li` is simply `clickDebug`. So this has nothing to do with the problem. (I added all the logging related code only after I recognized the problem, so I am sure it is not the cause.)

Comment: I reproduced the error with static data and a timeout instead of the Axios call. But I can't find a way to compare the broken event listeners to the good ones. If there is a way to turn them into JSON strings of reasonable length, one could compare them with git diff or something like that. But for all practical purposes these objects seem to be bottomless pits.

Comment: @Watchduck, am I understanding correctly then that you've definitely traced the error to be related to the axios calls then (or rather the impact of time due to the axios calls)?

Comment: Kind of. The static data version works, and `setTimeout` brings back the bug. The strange thing is, that the bug persists when the timeout has a delay of 0.